# Computation of 2-norm using Eigenvalues vs. Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matlab

For example, consider the matrix $B$: 
\begin{bmatrix}
   5 & -2\\
  -2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
computation of the 2-norm of $B$ using its eigenvalues (which is $6$ and $1$) yields 
$\sqrt{6}$ (since 6 is the largest eigenvalue of $B$).

But Matlab `norm(B,2)` yields `6.0000`

This is obviously the answer without the square root. What am I missing here? Is Matlab not square rooting the answer?

Comment: so should 6 be consider the 2-norm or $\sqrt{6}$?

Comment: @Moo you mean the *square root* of the largest eigenvalue of $A^HA$ (which is $6$, of course).

Comment: @Moo well, you did say "max eigenvalue of $A^HA$", which isn't correct, hence the correction.

Comment: Check the definition of $2$-norm of a matrix.  $6$ looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it can help you:
$$\bbox[yellow,5px] {\lVert B \rVert_{2}=\sqrt{\text {maximum eigenvalue of $B^TB$}  }}$$

---

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
   5 & -2\\
  -2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B^TB=\begin{bmatrix}
   29 & -14\\
  -14 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$$

\begin{aligned}|[B^TB]-\lambda I|&=\left|{\begin{bmatrix}29&-14\\-14&8\end{bmatrix}}-\lambda {\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}}\right|={\begin{vmatrix}29-\lambda &-14\\-14&8-\lambda \end{vmatrix}},\\&=\lambda ^{2}-37\lambda +36.\end{aligned}
$$\lambda=\{1,36\}$$
$$\text{max $\lambda$}=36$$

$\lVert B \rVert_{2}=\sqrt{\text {maximum eigenvalue of $B^TB$}  }=\sqrt{36}=6$